# PDFtk fill multiple values in single PDF form text field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdftk, fdf

I am little confused how to fill muiltiple values in single textbox using pdftk.

**What i have tried so far :**

```
$dataFields = `pdftk $pdf_path dump_data_fields`;
```

I am able to get the data fields with this commnad.

**Sample OUtPUT Of this :**

```
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: <<ProjectName>>
FieldNameAlt: <<ProjectName>>
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
---
FieldType: Text
FieldName: *<<ProjectAddress>><<ProjectCityState>>*
FieldNameAlt: <<ProjectAddress>><<ProjectCityState>>
FieldFlags: 0
FieldJustification: Left
```

But there are two values which i want to replace `<<ProjectAddress>><<ProjectCityState>>` with some other values for ex:, `21 jump street NY`.I can replace single value but how to replace multiple value dynamically from array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.so i found a solution for my question. what i have done :

```
1)save the field data in to one .txt file
2)using command `$dataFields = `pdftk $pdf_path dump_data_fields output output.txt``;
3)after that i have converted the file data in to array. using `$data = file('output.txt');` command and explode with new line.
4)then i put condition that if the string contains`FileName:` keyword and make new array.
5)and then compate it with my array and check.
```

Comment: You could also add `| grep FieldName` to filter names sooner and in one step.